# 'Currency' object has no attribute 'convert'

Tags: python, json, url, attributeerror

I am having this error saying:

> 'AttributeError: 'Currency' object has no attribute 'convert'.

I do not know what is incorrect in the code. Help is much appreciated.

````
import requests
import json

@currency

rates = {}

class Currency:
 def __init__(self, url):
     self.data= requests.get(url).json()
     self.currencies = self.data['rates']
 def extract_api_result (self, amount, from_currency, to_currency):
     inital_amount = amount
     if from_currency != "EUR":
         amount = amount / self.rates [from_currency]
     if to_currency == "EUR":
         return inital_amount, from_currency, '=', amount, to_currency
     else:
         return inital_amount, from_currency, '=', amount * self.rates [to_currency], to_currency

converter = Currency('https://api.frankfurter.app/latest')

print(converter.convert('INR','USD',100))
print(converter.convert(1.0,"EUR","USD"))
print(converter.convert(1.0,"GBP","USD"))
print(converter.convert(1.0,"CAD","GBP"))
print(converter.convert(1.0,"CAD","EUR"))```
````

Comment: Well, you see where your code says `converter.convert`, and the error message complains about the line of code that says that? In your own words, why do you think that should work, what should it do, and where do you think is the code that will make it work? Do you understand why the error message says `'Currency' object`? What do you think is the `'Currency' object` in your code that it's talking about? Do you know what an `attribute` is? Do you think that `'Currency' object`s are supposed to have an attribute with that name? According to the code that you've shown, do they?

Comment: On Stack Overflow, [you are expected to put in some effort yourself to solve the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). If you genuinely *don't know* how to take these most basic [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) steps - starting with *reading and understanding* the error message - then you need to drop everything, follow a general Python tutorial from the beginning, and not try to use third-party libraries to do your own projects until you understand the fundamentals.

Comment: Trust me, in the long run this will save you huge amounts of pain.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thank you for your response. I had another look realised I had input the print function wrong. I made a changed to the code `print(converter.extract_api_result('INR','USD',100))
print(converter.extract_api_result(1.0,"EUR","USD"))
print(converter.extract_api_result(1.0,"GBP","USD"))
print(converter.extract_api_result(1.0,"CAD","GBP"))` For some reason it still gives me an error. "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Currency' object has no attribute 'extract_api_result'" I am quite frustrated at this point